# DataTable horizontal scrolling with jquery Mobile not working

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, datatables, intel-xdk

When using datatables with jquery mobile, I can not seem to get a horizontal scroller going. I have tried every combination of sScrollX and sScrollY I can think of.

To see an example of the lack of vertical scroller, please try the webapp example I put up [here.](http://www.alrig.com/test)

On an iphone or some other small screen try the following:

1) Switch the slider from Graph to Table
2) Hit the favorites button
3) Scroll down the left panel and select "MSFT".

You will see only the first few columns. You can scroll up and down but not to the right.

I tried sScrollX and sScrollY but the scrolling is then inconsistent and buggy. At the moment I've disabled both and at least vertical scrolling works ok.

Any help would be much appreciated as I've now been fighting this for a week!

Please find the current datatables code below:

```
 var table = $('#table_container').dataTable( {
        "symbol": symbol,
        "exchange": exchange,
        "aoColumns": columnData,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "aTargets": [0],      "mRender": function (data, type, full) {return dateFormat(data)} },
        { "aTargets": [1],      "mRender": function (data, type, full) {return volumeNumber(data)} },
        { "aTargets": [8],      "mRender": function (data, type, full) {return volumeNumber(data)} },
        { "aTargets": [14],      "mRender": function (data, type, full) {return volumeNumber(data)} },                           
        { "aTargets": ["_all"], "mRender": function (data, type, full) {return numberWithCommas(parseFloat(data).toFixed(2))} },
        ],
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        //"sScrollX": "100%",
        //"sScrollY": "100%",
        //"sDom": 'r<"H"lf><"datatable-scroll"t><"F"ip>',                        
        "bScrollCollapse": false,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": str,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "fnServerData": function( sUrl, aoData, fnCallback ) {
            $.ajax( {
                "url": sUrl,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback,
                "dataType": "jsonp",
                "cache": false
            } );
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 6):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "110%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true
    } );
} );
```

Refer this [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bPaM7/10/)

Comment: Nope, that doesn't fix it either :-(

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the table in a div.

You can set the overflow value to auto.

```
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table-container{
  overflow: auto
}
```

another way is to set the overflow to hidden, and then set the overflow-x (horizontal scrolling) to scroll.  This has the benefit of also allowing you to set the -webkit-overflow-scrolling to touch, which will allow for momentum scrolling on mobile devices.

CSS

```
.table-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: @Stetler. This does not work. I still get the same issue. I have tried that for a while. You will notice that the table is already wrapped in a div: #main_container.  I've updated the css to include that but no luck as you can see.

Comment: I didnt realize you were using jQuery Mobile.  I personally dislike the framework because of situations like these.  did you try this solution? https://forum.jquery.com/topic/scrollview-jquery-mobile

Comment: I'm not sure the jquery scrollview plugin is still supported... that solution is over 2 years old..

Comment: btw, when I scroll down in mobile chrome and before the scroll quite finishes I can scroll horizontally as well, this only works for a brief second and stops working as soon as the scroll down (or up) is finished completely.  I think this has to do with the overlays placed by JQM, so you cant actually interact with the table container.

Comment: @Stetler -- I agree -- I get the same odd behavior. Is there a way to get rid of that? I tried coding this in intel xdk app framework and had the same problem. I'm not sure what else I can try! Is there a way to move the overlay to the top?

Comment: have you tried adding a z-index to the table_container_wrapper?  Just an idea, might work??

Comment: I think you are going to need to use a js solution like this http://iscrolljs.com/ .

Comment: adding a z-index to main_container (or table_container) didn't work. I've tried iscrolljs but that still fails as the element isn't registered due to the overlay

Comment: Hey, I've narrowed it down a bit further. Take a look here: perhaps you will know? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046704/jquery-mobile-not-passing-event-down-correctly

Answer (score 1):

I have inspected the CSS of your APP from the link you provided.

To get the table to scroll in any direction independently  you will need to set a desired width and height in your **.dataTables_wrapper** class. Vertical scrolling works in your APP because the Table is not actually scrolling itself but the Whole Page is. If your APP will not have any other content below the table then the table height can be set all the way to the bottom of the Page or else you will need to have a small Gap at the bottom so a user can touch and scroll further down the Page. Also If you are aiming your app on different mobiles then you need some jquery code to calculate screen size and update the width and height in the **.dataTables_wrapper** class on the fly so the table will fit the screen from left and right and to the bottom. Any excess width and height will be scrolled if the table contents are longer than the size. If the APP is just for one mobile then its easy to play around with the width and height in the class to get the desired size of the table.

Example

```
 .dataTables_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
```

Your **main_container** css should be like this, so delete the rest. Otherwise you will have another horizontal scroll bar that does nothing.

```
  #main_container {
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Although scroll bars are usually hidden from mobile browsers unlike desktop browsers, if you want add this css trick to hide them from view. This trick only works for webkit browsers such as Google/Safari/Native Android etc.

```
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 0px;
   }
```

It may be a good idea to you have Fixed Table Header so a person can see what data relates to the columns when they are scrolling. There are lots of ways to achieve this, below i added a  link i found

http://fixedheadertable.com/

Comment: I implemented your changes, but still no luck. It doesn't scroll right. Try to go to alrig.com/test on a device like an iphone and you will see. The css files are as you asked. I tried putting !important just in case and still no change.

Comment: I just checked on iphone and you are correct. There something wrong with CSS code altogether. I had another look and noticed some IFRAMES in the main page before i chose a ticker for the table. Is the table inside an INFRAME? If so check --   https://coderwall.com/p/c-aqqw  -- for a solution to scroll inside the Frame. Otherwise check this link on an IPHONE to see a Demo for Scrollable table (demo) --- http://creativeandcode.com/demos/responsive-tables/ --- (Source) ---  http://creativeandcode.com/simple-solution-for-responsive-tables/ I hust tested the demo and works perfectly on the IPHONE.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I'd like to stick with datatables as they make it easy to pass information via jsonp. I don't have to code the table myself.