# jquery mobile not passing event down correctly

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, datatables, mobile-application, intel-xdk

I seem to have a weird problem with intelxdk and jquery mobile.

If I select an element, the scrolling works fine. If nothing is selected, then the touch event is registered properly. This is best explained through the attached two images.

How do I get it to focus properly? .focus() doesn't work.

Please see the attached to pictures for clarity.

Here the scrolling doesn't work.
[image: Here the scrolling doesn't work]

Here the scrolling works.
[image: Works]

It's almost as if the event is not propogated down all the way.

**Edit**
As requested by Tasos, here's the first picture with the relevant div's expanded.

[image]

Comment: in your first screenshot, can you expand the DIV (wrap ui-mobile-viewport ...) and take a screenshot again a post it.

Comment: @Tasos, uploaded, thanks for looking at it!